# Modx изменение содержимого Дополнительного поля

Tags: modx

Здравствуйте знатоки, вопрос такой. Создал нового пользователя с ограниченными параметрами менеджера, но есть некоторые ресурсы, в которых присутствуют дополнительные поля, но в правах доступа этого Дополнительного поля нет этого пользователя. 
[image: Должен ещё и менеджер отображаться]
Соответственно вопрос почему не отображается, и как сделать что бы виден был пользователь в Доп параметрах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как я вижу, у вас уже есть пользователи, которым доступна эта tv-шка. Это Администратор.

Стало быть, нужно для Менеджера также настроить доступ к этой tv-шке.

А вообще, по-хорошему, определиться, зачем ограничивать доступ к картинке новости для какой-либо группы пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в настройках tv параметра, в источнике файла, нужно источник файлов который виден для данного пользователя